# ORA-00936: missing expression case statement

Tags: oracle, select, case

Received the above error when executing this select with a case statement.  I tried several methods, but cannot get the syntax correct.

```
SELECT m.md_security_id,
   thv.unit_qty,
   thv.contract_value_amt,
   thv.contract_currency_cd,
   (case when
   THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'B'
   then select THV.SENDER_ORG_ID as BORROWER_ORG_ID,
           select THV.RECIPIENT_ORG_ID as LENDER_ORG_ID
     end),
   (case when
   THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'L'
   THEN select THV.RECIPIENT_ORG_ID as BORROWER_ORG_ID,
            select THV.SENDER_ORG_ID as LENDER_ORG_ID
    end)   
    FROM eqmddev.txn_header_mv thv,
   eqmddev.md_security m,
   eqmddev.security_xref_vw_tbl x
   WHERE     m.isin = x.security_id
   AND ThV.SECURITY_MASTER_ID = X.SECURITY_MASTER_ID
   AND M.EXCHANGE_CD = X.EXCHANGE_CD
```

Comment: You better explain what you want to achieve. Your current query doesn't make much sense

Comment: Agree. Thought I understood what you needed until I tried to edit it and fix it, then realized....some stuff is missing. That select inside your case is a problem; you can't return multiple columns from a case as far as I know

Comment: More I look at it, why not skip the case entirely, and return borrower_org_id in one column, lender_org_id in the next column? Seems your layout is *very* confusing in its current state.

Comment: The case is needed for business logic.  I guess if I cannot return multiple selects inside the case statement I'll need to use another approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT m.md_security_id,
   thv.unit_qty,
   thv.contract_value_amt,
   thv.contract_currency_cd,
   case 
    when THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'B' then THV.SENDER_ORG_ID 
    when THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'L' THEN THV.RECIPIENT_ORG_ID 
   end AS BORROWER_ORG_ID,
   case 
    when THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'B' then THV.RECIPIENT_ORG_ID 
    when THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD = 'L' THEN THV.SENDER_ORG_ID 
   end AS LENDER_ORG_ID,
FROM eqmddev.txn_header_mv thv,
   eqmddev.md_security m,
   eqmddev.security_xref_vw_tbl x
WHERE     m.isin = x.security_id
   AND ThV.SECURITY_MASTER_ID = X.SECURITY_MASTER_ID
   AND M.EXCHANGE_CD = X.EXCHANGE_CD
```

Basically, you can't return multiple columns from a CASE statement. Treat it as a conditional replacement for a single column. In the example above, I used the same CASE conditions for both `BORROWER_ORG_ID` and `LENDER_ORG_ID` aliases.

On the side note, you should also consider including an ELSE statement into your CASEs. Otherwise, if `THV.BORROW_LOAN_TYPE_CD` is not `B` or `L` you would get NULLs

Comment: Thanks Cha!!!!  Works perfectly.  I saw examples with the "end as <column name>", but didn't realize you use the alias there.